# date and time from epoch in seconds WITH timezone and daylight saving

Tags: bash, datetime

I'm trying to get the current date/time seconds from epoch in bash.
I did it with

```
date +%s
```

But this doesn't handle my timezone and daylight saving.

Something like
1) get epoch
2) add 3600 (i'm in rome, so GMT+1)
3) add 3600 only if we are on daylight saving time

It's possible in bash?

Comment: *"But this doesn't handle my timezone and daylight savings..."  Yes it does. Epoch seconds an absolute measure; for any given point in real time, it is the same exactly the same everywhere.   The time zone does not matter; that's applied when it is converted into local time.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way:

```
#!/bin/sh
OFFSET=$(date +%z)
SIGN=${OFFSET:0:1}
HOURS=${OFFSET:1:2}
MINUTES=${OFFSET:3:2}
EPOCH=$(date +%s)
echo $(( ${EPOCH} ${SIGN} ( ${HOURS} * 3600 + ${MINUTES} * 60 ) ))
```

Comment: Referring back to my comment on the question **never use the value calculated above with any standard tools** because epoch seconds are *always* considered to be an absolute measure.

Answer (score 0):

`date [-u|--utc|--universal]` returns the UTC representation whereas `date` returns the system's local time with regard to DST (Daylight Saving Time).

*Example (assuming 2016-06-01 is within DST):*

Get Local time from your timezone (GMT+1 +1 for DST)

```
$ date -d '2016-06-01 02:00:00+0200' +'%s = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
1464739200 = 2016-06-01 02:00:00
```

Get UTC (epoch) from your timezone (GMT+1 +1 for DST)

```
$ date -u -d '2016-06-01 02:00:00+0200' +'%s = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
1464739200 = 2016-06-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this usage of date is specific to the version from GNU coreutils (i.e. used in Linux).  The `-d` option doesn't exist (or does something different) in OSX, FreeBSD, NetBSD, Solaris, etc.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the output of `date +%s` is the same with or without `-u` (including the above example).